# How do I duplicate a VueJS project?

Tags: vue.js, npm, vue-cli

When trying to simply duplicate a whole VueJS project using `cp -r project clone_project`, I get the following error when running `npm run serve` from the `clone_project`directory:

```
> design@0.1.0 serve /Users/path_to_clone_project/clone_project
> vue-cli-service serve

internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:613
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '../package.json'
Require stack:
- /Users/path_to_clone_project/clone_project/node_modules/.bin/vue-cli-service
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:610:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:526:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:666:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:16:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/path_to_clone_project/clone_project/node_modules/.bin/vue-cli-service:5:25)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:759:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:770:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:628:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:555:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:824:10)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! design@0.1.0 serve: `vue-cli-service serve`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the design@0.1.0 serve script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

The original project was created using the Vue CLI tool. I don't understand the error since the `package.json`file was copied as expected with the rest of the project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delete your `node_modules` folder and run `npm install`.

`npm install` will create `node_modules` folder and install all of the packages that are defined in package.json.

Then run `npm run serve`

Comment: **Sidenote:** Running `npm install` in the  new _"clone_project"_ directory only guarantees an exact duplicate copy if either a _[npm-package-lock.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package-lock.json)_ or _[npm-shrinkwrap.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/shrinkwrap.json)_ file were copied to the _"clone_project"_ directory. If neither of the aforementioned `.json` files were copied to the _"clone_project"_ directory prior to `npm install` you may get newer pkg versions installed as new patches of a pkg(s) may have been released since they were added/installed in the original src directory.

Comment: You may want to consider using [`rsync`](https://ss64.com/bash/rsync.html) instead of [`cp`](https://ss64.com/bash/cp.html) to duplicate the directory. For instance: `rsync -a project/ clone_project`